# How to filter posts loaded in theme with plugin in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I want to make plugin that edit posts and add something to their title WHEN they are getting in realtime. like posts in homepage . I just want to make few changes to post properties.
i already found an solution about this but i don't know how to make it work.
[link to solution](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/242058/is-there-a-get-posts-filter-that-can-alter-replace-the-output-completely).
thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can use a WordPress hook, that's how I'd do it.

In your `functions.php` add this piece of code:

```
 <?php 
      function populate_posts_data( $posts, $query ) {
           global $wpdb;

           if ( !count( $posts ) ) 
               return $posts;  // posts array is empty send it back with thanks.

           while ( $posts as $post ) {
               // do whatever you want for each post, alter its data, etc
               $post->title = $post->title . ' Edited');
           }
           return $posts;
       }
       add_filter( 'the_posts', 'populate_posts_data' );
 ?>
```

Thank you, hope it helps you.

Comment: thanks it works. I actually found that hook before but the problem was that i changed global post in that NOT posts argument from filter.Thanks again anyway